# Why is std::variant unable to hold array object types while union can?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++17, variant, c++20

Here is simple example,
We can define a low level `union` like this :

```
static union
{
    uint64_t a;
    uint8_t b[8];
};
```

but we cannot declare `std::variant` like this(please do not care about syntax,correct me if I am wrong!, just grab the idea)

```
std::variant<uint64_t, uint8_t[8]> v
```

[cppReference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant) stated clearly that,

> **Template parameters**
>
> *Types*   -   the types that may be stored in this variant. All types must be (possibly cv-qualified) non-array object type

also,**MSVC-v141**(C++17) compiler has given a compilation error:

> Error C2338   variant requires all of the Ts to be non-array
>   object types ([variant.variant]/2).

---

`std::variant` is primarily a class template hence,
 ***Problem is it unable to deduce array type storage, since it requires only data layout/representation*** ?

Comment: this might help you - https://www.ojdip.net/2013/10/implementing-a-variant-type-in-cpp/

Comment: I'd guess it has to do with arrays being non-copyable except as data members, and having implicit conversion to pointer. All that complication can be avoided simply by not supporting raw arrays. You can always use a `std::array`.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf you meant like this -> `std::variant<uint64_t, std::array<uint8_t>[8]> v` something like that?

Comment: yes [[[[[[[[[[[[

Comment: @BuddhikaChaturanga `std::array<uint8_t, 8>`

Comment: Thank you guys...

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Support for arrays was removed in [P0510R0](http://wg21.link/p0510r0) after [national body comment US116](http://wg21.link/p0488r0), which I reproduce below:

> Support for
>    array alternatives does not seem to work 
>   as expected.
>     For example, if any of the alternatives 
>   is an array, the current specification fails to satisfy the 
>   Requires clause for all 6 relational operators, and 
>   loses (shall not participate in overload resolution) the 
>   copy constructor, move constructor, copy-assignment 
>   operator, move-assignment operator (although the 
>   swap functions will work correctly).
>     It is difficult to 
>   activate an array alternative 
>   - to the best of my 
>   understanding, it must be emplaced with no 
>   arguments in order to value-initialize the array, and 
>   then the value of each element may be assigned as 
>   needed.
>     Many of these issues would be resolved if 
>   array alternatives were implemented by storing a 
>   std::array instead, and then exposing the exposition-only array member (of the std::array) to the get 
>   functions, but that seems like an experimental change 
>   that should be investigated for the next standard.  For 
>   C++17, we should drop support for arrays (but not 
>   std::array) as alternatives, in order to leave freedom to support them properly in the next standard.

It seems likely that during the initial revisions of the `std::variant` proposal, not much thought was given to the possibility of array types, although some thought *was* given to the case of reference and void types (support for these was also removed in P0510R0), and some of the revisions implicitly forbade arrays by imposing the `Destructible` requirement (which is not present in the final standard text). Once the draft standard was sent out to the national member bodies, someone noticed that arrays pose difficulties because they cannot be copied, moved, or compared in the expected fashion. All of these issues could, perhaps, be solved by special-casing arrays in the specification and implementation (member-wise comparison, etc.), but this work was left for a future revision of the standard.